# Wpf: Image Control does not support .TGA files

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmapimage

In my application I am using Images, these images can be .tga(Targa Graphic) file as well, when I am creating instance of BitmapImage using .tga file, it throws exception saying "No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.".

Is there any other way to work with .tga file in wpf?
How can I use these(.tga) files just like any other .jpg(Image file) in wpf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) is a free open source library for images and it has a c# wrapper.

Comment: April 2015: Just seconding this as the best answer years later.  FreeImage works today in Win8 and Win10, and supports the alpha channel of the Targa image, which is what most people are after if they are using the Targa format.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.netframeworkdev.com/windows-presentation-foundation-wpf/wpf--load-image-from-stream--error-no-imaging-component-found-75844.shtml

try this

Comment: 30dec2014 - Server not found

Answer (score 0):

TGA is not a very widespread format... The exception means exactly what it says : WPF doesn't have a suitable decoder for this format. You will have to convert it to a known format.

Comment: How can I convert it programatically? Is there any converter available?

Comment: It seems that ImageMagick supports the TGA format. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Comment: didn't find way to use it, of course i am from .net background and don't understand C++

Comment: TGA is *definitely* a widespread format. It used to be the standard for uncompressed 24 / 32 bit graphics (textures) in render-land.

Answer (score 0):

Can't vouch for the quality of this project, but you might look here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/TargaImage.aspx

Here's the TGA specification if you want to roll your own: local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/dataformats/tga/